# Re-position WPF window after resizing to mouse location

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, wpf-controls

I am creating a small game that resizes the main window to fit a growing board. I want to re-position the window to keep the button that was clicked under the mouse after resizing. Currently, when clicked the board gets wider and moves the button away from the mouse.

How do I define the button as the anchor point when I move the window?

Comment: Please add your current code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to use the button as an anchor point. But after a little thinking, i came up with a code that can work for you.
Basically, i'm using the mouse relative to the button position before and after the resize to move the window accordingly. I hope it helps.

```
private void Btn1Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int widthGrowth = 50;
    int heightGrowth = 80;

    Button btn = sender as Button;
    Point oldMousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(btn);

    Width += widthGrowth;
    Height += heightGrowth;

    Point newMousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(btn);

    Left += newMousePosition.X - oldMousePosition.X;
    Top += newMousePosition.Y - oldMousePosition.Y;
}
```